# Make My account edit-account fields readonly in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to make woocommerce my-account/edit-account/ page email, or last name or another field. One field or two fields, ReadOnly.

My solution is edit form-edit-account.php file in plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount folder and edit form-edit-account.php file and add **readonly** to end of tags and work correctly. For example:

```
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
<label for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" readonly />
</p>
```

But I need make this change only from function.php file. Is this possible? I need code for functions.php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use jQuery instead (here for the "billing_mobile_phone" field):

```
add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'make_phone_field_readonly' );
function make_phone_field_readonly(){
    // Only for account fields
    if( is_account_page() ): ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            $('form.edit-account input#billing_mobile_phone').prop('readonly', true );
        });
    </script>
    <?php endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Or as in your penultimate question, you will use the hooked function adding `readonly` attribute to your additional fields:

```
// Display the mobile phone field
// add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start', 'add_billing_mobile_phone_to_edit_account_form' ); // At start
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_billing_mobile_phone_to_edit_account_form' ); // After existing fields
function add_billing_mobile_phone_to_edit_account_form() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>
     <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="billing_mobile_phone"><?php _e( 'Mobile phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--phone input-text" name="billing_mobile_phone" id="billing_mobile_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->billing_mobile_phone ); ?>" readonly />
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

So at all you have 3 alternatives:

- Add the readonly attribute with jQuery (may be the best way)
- Overriding the template via the theme (adding the readonly attribute)
- Add custom account fields with the read only attribute

Comment: Merci; Work fine. But this code add duplicate filed to edit account page. example: if replace billing_mobile_phone with billing_email for make billing_email field in edit account page ( readonly ). during use code for Available fields.

Comment: Updated with a jquery solution, that will work also on existing template fields.

Comment: yes. i paste only your jquery code to functions.php and replace billing_mobile_phone in your code with billing_email ; but not change in email field in woocommerce edit account page . still changable or writable!

Comment: @ahmadsh My code just perfectly works… What is not working is your changes… Why? Because **It's not** `billing_email`, but **`account_email`** instead that you need!!! … There is no `billing_email` on default account fields.

Comment: yes. account_email or account_name or account_phone work correctly. merci